# Rewriting timers in .NET with lambda

Tags: c#, .net, timer

```
var timeToWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
var interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
var t = new Timer(s =>
    {
        tracker.ProcessAuditLogs();
    }, null, timeToWait, interval);
```

I'm looking to run a timer or an indefinite period of time, as long as my program/service is running. Will the above work in a production environment?

Comment: Could you give us a bit more context? What are your concerns about this code?

Comment: Would you please add some representative conditions that might make it fail in a production environment?  Are you worried, for example, that the new GC algorithms for servers might cause an inadvertent collection of your timer?

Comment: Yes! that is my concern.  I didn't know how to word it previously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I converted my timer loops to Reactive Extensions a while back to avoid the memory leaks created by event subscriptions and event handlers.  A snippet doing the same thing as yours is...

```
        var timer = Observable
            .Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
            .Subscribe(q =>
                {   // this executes every 3 seconds in a detached loop 
                    Console.WriteLine("do something here " + q);
                });
        // other work goes here
        GC.KeepAlive(timer);
```

Of interest here is the last line.  This tells the GC that the object should not be garbage collected until it is reached.  You can use the same strategy for your event driven timer.

If you wanted a fascinating glimpse into the new garbage collector introduced in 4.5, Maoni Stephens (the lady who actually wrote the GC) made a video that's a 'must see'...  http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Maoni-Stephens-CLR-45-Server-Background-GC

Comment: I doubt very much that `GC.KeepAlive` works here. It only keeps the target in memory until it is reached, but it doesn't keep it alive after that. So it seems useless here.

Comment: Good point.  I amended the code fragment

Comment: @GarryVass: I think the problem is more in your description ("object should not be garbage collected even if it goes out of scope").  It would be better to say the object won't be garbage collected until `GC.KeepAlive(timer)` is reached.

Comment: @Brian, thanks again.  It's the problem with downsizing code to relevant snippets for pasting.  And yes, in implementation, the whole thing should be (and presumably would be) wrapped.